# Is there a way to add days to a [$datefield.displayValue] in JSON?

Tags: json, sharepoint

I am trying to figure a way to add 14 days to StartDate field and display it as the due date with:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$StartDate] == '', 'Uh oh!', [$StartDate.displayValue] + 14)"
```

I would like to keep the displayValue, but when I do the above it just includes the 14 as text and does not add days to the StartDate. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: is due date a Calculated column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add milliseconds to any date and the result will be a new date. For example, to add a day to a date, you'd add (`24*60*60*1000`).

So use the below instead should work for you:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$StartDate] == '', 'Uh oh!', [$StartDate] + 14*24*60*60*1000)"
```

Update:

```
   "txtContent": "=if([$StartDate] == '', 'Uh oh!',toLocaleDateString ([$StartDate] + 14*24*60*60*1000))
```

Comment: This worked! But it is showing "3:00:00 AM" at the end, is there a way to hide that?

Comment: You could use toLocaleDateString() method to display date only. See my updated answer.